# How to get a list of latitude longitude points for Pedestrian navigation using Google Directions API

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, map-directions

I need to fetch the list of latitude and longitudes of a complete route to be used by pedestrians. I know i can get route segment points using the Google Directions API but problem comes when there is a turn  in the route. I need very accurate direction navigation at step by step accuracy.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Wahib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: it looks so messy to write script(Maybe it is answered only for display)

Please check minimum(j:p) of:
distance(result.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0].steps[s].startpoint,
         result.getDirections().routes[0].overview_path[p]);

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am able to fetch array of all latitude and longitude values by using                                                   var overviewPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(routes[0].overview_polyline.points);